# SQL Server : how to parse a column value and insert in multiple columns of separate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, insert

I have a table CUSTOMER(ID,ADDRESS) with following values

```
1,ROCKVILLE MDUS 
2,JERSEY CITY NJUS
3,NEW YORK CITY NYUS
.
.
.
```

I want to load the above values in separate table `STG_TXN(CITY,STATE,COUNTRY)`. Last two chars in `COUNTRY`, the second last two chars in `STATE` and everything before that in `CITY`.

```
ROCKVILLE,MD,US
JERSEY CITY,NJ,US
NEW YORK CITY,NY,US
.
.
.

 INSERT INTO STG_TXN
    SELECT (how can I parse the value to be selected as CITY, STATE and COUNTRY here ? ) 
    FROM dbo.CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Can you tell us (in excruciating detail) the rules for parsing that address?

Comment: Are the state and country always 2 characters long?

Comment: @marosoaie - I have updated the details in my question as to how I want the data to be inserted. Yes, country and state will be always 2 chars long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO STG_TXN
select SUBSTRING(address,0,LEN(address) - 4),SUBSTRING(address,LEN(address) - 3,2)
,SUBSTRING(address,LEN(address) - 1,2)
from CUSTOMER
```

However, this only works if the the length of state or country is 2

Comment: Thanks @Adel Sal - However, after returning 20K records out of 2 million, the query is failing on SUBSTRING(address,0,LEN(address) - 4), giving error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function in Sql Server"

The query returns all 2 million records when I comment out the first substring column.

Any idea?

Comment: That means there is an address value with a length less than/or equal to 4. Run the following and you'll get it: select address from customer where LEN(address) <= 4

Comment: You were absolutely right. I got 154 records with a wide spaces and no value. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi Just add the condition `where LEN(address) > 4` to the insert statement to exclude those records

Comment: No, I want to add those records too becasue they have other information (i.e. other columns) Is it possible to add those columns using a SQL case?

Comment: Thanks Adel, I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi then you can replace the first one by `select case when LEN(address) > 4 then  SUBSTRING(address,0,LEN(address) - 4) else address end` but that is not practical since state and country are also null. I advice you make two insert statements for both conditions.

Comment: thanks @Adel ! I used the above case condition for all 3 columns and now I am getting all 2 million records! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO STG_TXN
select 
    LEFT(@teststr,LEN(@teststr)-4) city, 
    LEFT(RIGHT(@teststr,4),2) state, 
    RIGHT(@teststr,2) country 
from customer
```

Comment: +1 for simplest.  (But:  why is every answerer assuming that the database is case-insensitive?)

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
INSERT INTO STG_TXN
select 
substring(address,1, len(address)-4),
reverse(substring(reverse(address),3,2)),
reverse(substring(reverse(address),1,2))
from customer
```